# Change which marketplaces are available?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-marketplace

If I download Eclipse 3.7.2 I get the markeplace functionality with some predefined public marketplaces; Eclipse.org marketplace, Yoxos marketplace, Obeo marketplace and Testing solutions marketplace.

If I want to remove one or more of these, or add a link to my own marketplace, how would I do that?

Edit: Found out how to add my own marketplace: http://wiki.eclipse.org/EPP/MPC/Developer_Guide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this is what I've figured out so far.

The markeplace client has an extensionpoint, `org.eclipse.epp.mpc.ui.catalog`, where a catalog is defined. As I understand it, that entry shall lead to a URL that implements a certain REST api and that url defines which Marketplaces are available.

The client is per default set up to connect to http://marketplace.eclipse.org/catalogs/api/p where the four marketplaces are listed.

So it seems I would have to:

- Create my own webservice that implements the correct REST api, which [seems difficult but doable](http://openchrom.wordpress.com/2012/03/13/own-marketplace-server-part-ii/)

  - It would then need to define which marketplaces I want to use
- Create an Eclipse package that doesnt include the default marketplace client
- Create my own version of the marketplace client that connects to my webservice

In short; Way to much work for me at this time. :)

My references:

- http://wiki.eclipse.org/Marketplace/REST
- http://wiki.eclipse.org/EPP/MPC